# Reading models into ViewModels and other way round in MVVM - best practice -

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I would like to get an insight into your daily work :P

How do you read the Person data into the PersonViewModel ?

Is it just a

```
PersonViewModel pVM = staticHelper.ConvertPersonToPersonViewModel(person);
```

or is there something cooler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply include the Person object in the view model, don't try to copy the object at all.

```
public class PersonViewModel 
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    ... plus other properties your view model might need
}
```

then in your controller:

```
PersonViewModel pVM = new PersonViewModel { Person = person } ;
```

Comment: so in my ViewModel I have this: public string FirstName { return Person.FirstName;}, Hey thats smart!

Comment: Thats one way, but you don't need to do that.  In your view (page), simply refer to Model.Person.FirstName

Comment: but thats the way Josh smith is doing it! :P The ViewModel delegates the binding to the model... btw. How do you aggregate ViewModel with master-detail relation like CustomerViewModel has a list of OrderViewModel ?

Comment: Who?  In a master-detail your view model would simply include both the master object and list<T> detail.  Public class ViewModel { public Master Master { get; set; }   public List<Detail> Detail { get; set; }  }.    Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

[Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is the best thing since the `for` loop, maybe even the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Some folks advocate [copy constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Others might [use reflection to copy properties](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a4264125-fcb0-4757-9d78-ff541dfbcb56/net-reflection--copy-cl.aspx).

Of course, nothing says you can't use reflection to copy properties while in a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the point of the viewmodel.
The viewmodel is supposed to be a mapping / interface to the model, not a copy of it.

Comment: never said its a copy, but the way I see it VERY often implemented makes it look like a copy...

Comment: It may LOOK like a copy because it's a MAPPING.